# Merge array after getting last element of a query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, date, mongodb-query

Hello I am doing a query of a nested date and it does return an array, how could I aggregate the last item of every array ?

```
db.ft.find({ "published.dateTime": {
    $gte: ISODate("2014-01-01"), $lt: ISODate("2020-02-01")}}, { drafts: 1, _id: 0 })
```

This returns

```
/* 1 */
{
    "drafts" : [ 
        104493, 
        162076, 
        161034, 
        186662
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "drafts" : [ 
        118987, 
        173786
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "drafts" : [ 
        11993, 
        173787
    ]
}
```

Ideally I want an array with [186662 , 173786, 173787]

[EDIT 1]

I tried with `{ "drafts": {$slice:-1}}` it does work but I get the whole object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `drafts` elements from all documents to be pulled into one array then you need to use [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Your filter condition go in here */
  {
    $match: {} 
  },
  /** Re-create drafts field with last element from 'drafts' array */
  {
    $addFields: { "drafts": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$drafts", -1 ] } }
  },
  /** group on empty string '' or null to group all docs without any filter &
   * push value of 'drafts' field from all docs to new 'drafts' field */
  {
    $group: { _id: "", drafts: { $push: "$drafts" } }
  },
  /** Optional, remove `_id :''` from response */
  {
    $project: { _id: 0 }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AbTsxeyXVeI)

Comment: Thank you for some reason when I add the match it doesn't work :/ 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/pCIyTVRDOZX

Comment: @rad : You've a typo here : `"published.dateTime"` it should be  `"published.dataTime"`. **test** : (https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJr9FpJTNLd)